# Powershell Copy-Item Error when moving Bookmarks

Tags: windows, powershell

One of my scripts is to move Google Chrome bookmarks from one machine on the network to another. When I run the script, it appears to run and then throws a Copy-Item error. Pretty sure there's something wrong with my file path, but I can't figure out what it is.

Code first, error follows:

```
     [CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [String]$SourceComputerName,
    [String]$DestinationComputerName,
    [String]$UserName
)
BEGIN {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
     $CMDOUT=@{ #This is used so that the function accepts -Verbose / -Debug parameters
        Verbose=If ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose -eq $true) { $true } else { $false };
        Debug=If ($PSBoundParameters.Debug -eq $true) { $true } else { $false }
    }

    $SourcePath = '\\' + $SourceComputerName + '\C$\users\' + $UserName + '\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default' #Transfer Bookmarks from here
    $DestinationPath = '\\' + $DestinationComputerName + '\C$\users\' + $UserName + '\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default' #Transfer Bookmarks to here
}

PROCESS{
    #Create copy of destination backup file, make sure not to overwrite other backup files that might exsist
    If(Test-Path ($DestinationPath + '\Bookmarks')){
        $i = 1
        do{
            $BackupPath = ($DestinationPath + '\Bookmarks') + '_' + $i.ToString('000') + '.old'
            $i++
        }
        while(Test-Path $BackupPath)
        Copy-Item -Path ($SourcePath + '\Bookmarks') -Destination $BackupPath @CMDOUT
    }

    #Copy Bookmarks to DestinationComputer
    Copy-Item -Path ($SourcePath + '\Bookmarks') -Destination ($DestinationPath + '\Bookmarks') -Force @CMDOUT
    #Replace the Chrome create Bookmark backup (.bak) file
    Copy-Item -Path ($SourcePath + '\Bookmarks') -Destination ($DestinationPath + '\Bookmarks.bak') -Force @CMDOUT

    #Copy Favicons (for bookmarks)
    If(Test-Path ($DestinationPath + '\Favicons')){
        Copy-Item -Path ($SourcePath + '\Favicons') -Destination ($DestinationPath + '\Favicons') -Force @CMDOUT
    }
}
END{
}
```

}

```
    Copy-Item : The network path was not found
  At C:\Users\Shane.goldsberry\PowerShellScripts\PS1\MigrateChromeBookmarks.ps1:61 char:9  
    Copy-Item -Path ($SourcePath + '\Bookmarks') -Destination ($D ...
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand



    Copy-Item : The network path was not found At C:\Users\Shane.goldsberry\PowerShellScripts\PS1\MigrateChromeBookmarks.ps1:63 char:9  Copy-Item -Path ($SourcePath + '\Bookmarks') -Destination ($D ...  
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. My guess would be that you're not running the script with enough permissions to access the `C$` share. Try running PowerShell as administrator.

Comment: Check your permissions on the network. Can you access the %LocalAppdata% paths on both these machines>

Comment: @Theo I can access the path on both machines. I've tried running PowerShell as an admin as well as setting the execution policy to unrestricted, but still getting the same error.

Comment: sounds weird.. The only reason i can think of is that on the `$SourceComputerName` the user specified in `$UserName` has not run Chrome before and therefore does not have the path set up in his profile. Try writing out the path and put that in your "Run command" (Windows + R)

Comment: I'd do a `Test-Path -PathType Leaf` on the sourcepath first. Especially since the Bookmarks has no extension and is a file.. You do test on the destination, but do not check if the source file is actually present before you start copy.

Comment: I'll give that a try this afternoon and let you know what comes of it. I'm pretty sure it's something simple I'm just missing